# Defining a global App Namespace with Require.js and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, amd

I'm new to Require.js, and I'm trying to do something which I thought would be simple but is starting to be a pain.

I'm trying to define a global namespace for my Backbone application, and load it as a module. Here is my namespace (main.js):

```
define(
['jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'GlobalRouter'
],
function($, _, Backbone) {
var App= {
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {},
    Routers: {},
    init: function() {
        new App.Routers.GlobalRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
}
return App;

});
```

and here is my config.js file:

```
require.config({
// your configuration key/values here
baseUrl: "js", // generally the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute for the top level script
paths: {
    'jquery' : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min',
    'underscore': 'vendor/underscore-min',
    'backbone': 'vendor/backbone-min',
    'marionette': 'vendor/backbone.marionette',
    'main' : 'main'
}, // set up custom paths to libraries, or paths to RequireJS plugins
shim: {
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },

    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },

    'main' : {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery', 'backbone', 'GlobalRouter'],
        exports: 'TEWC'
    }

} // used for setting up all Shims (see below for more detail)
});

define([
'jquery',
   'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'main'
],
function($, _, Backbone, App, GlobalRouter) {
console.log(App)
alert('hit ')
  $(function() {
       App.init();
    });
 }
```

);

and for good measure, here is my router:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'main'
],
function($, _, Backbone, TEWC) {

TEWC.Routers.GlobalRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "" : "index",
        "documents/:id" : "edit",
        "login" : "login"
    },

    edit: function(id) {
        alert('edit')
    },

    index: function() {
        alert('index')
    },

    login: function() {
        alert('login')
    }
});

});
```

In the past, I was getting a 'app is undefined error'. Now, I get a load timeout error after a  few minutes that says this:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: main
```

However, the alert doesn't fire, and main.js doesn't seem to get loaded, but I believe router does, and it doesn't bark that TEWC is undefined -- so it may be loading even though it's not in my Network tab?

This is probably a rookie question -- does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does not define GlobalRouter yet it get's passed to the define callback

```
define([
'jquery',
   'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'main'
],
function($, _, Backbone, App, GlobalRouter) {
console.log(App)
alert('hit ')
  $(function() {
       App.init();
    });
 }
```

add `GlobalRouter` to `define`

Secondly, when it fails to load `main` ..can you check from console what URL it is trying to access? It most probably is a mis-configuration.

Comment: It was this combined with Addy Osmani's TodoMVC with backbone and require (https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require) that made the difference! Thanks!

Comment: streetlight: can you tell what was the exact problem? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @JohnEdward, I believe i had to configure main.js in an AMD-style, with a define function and so on. Also, it is extremely important to make sure that the order of files you are defining also match the order of things in the function parameters -- I believe that was the key. Does this help at all?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken your problem is that in `config.js`, after the require.config(), your define() should be a require() instead.

Explaining further. You currently have:

```
define([
'jquery',
   'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'main'
...
```

This `define` should be a `require` because this is code you want executed; it is not a module definition.

This and of course the missing `GlobalRouter` dependency as noted earlier.